# Not able to perform parallel write operations in ADLS from Databricks notebook. OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am facing this error when performing write operation in `foreach()` on a dataframe. The piece of code was working fine for over 3 months but started failing since last week.

To give some context, I have a dataframe extract_df which contains 2 columns xml_full_name and content. I use the below code to write these records as xmls to a target folder in ADLS.

```
extract_df.foreach(write_file)
```

`write_file` is defined as:

```
def write_file(row):
    with open(row.extract_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(row.content)
```

The notebook also uses `spark.write` command to write some parquets which is working fine.

On further investigation, I found that this issue could be related to parallelism and as a work around I tried the below:

```
for row in extract_df.collect():
    with open(row.extract_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(row.content)
```

This works which means the connection is fine but parallelism isn't working. However, this can't be used as a fix though as it will bring down the performance.

Anyone here has faced this issue? If this is related to some configuration, any suggestions on what and where I can check. All inputs are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below:

```
import os

def write_file_partition(rows):
    for row in rows:
        with open(row.xml_full_name, "w") as f:
            f.write(row.content)
extract_df.foreachPartition(write_file_partition)
write_file_partition(extract_df.collect())
```

**Results:**

[image]

In the above code, the `foreachPartition()` method is used to apply a function to each partition of the RDD/DataFrame.

I have defined a function `write_file_partition()` which takes a partition of the extract_df DataFrame and writes the content to the file.

You can then call the `foreachPartition()` method on the extract_df DataFrame and pass the `write_file_partition()` function as an argument. This will apply the function to each partition of the DataFrame in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added a `try` block around the _foreach_ logic and added the _foreachPartition_ logic in an `except` block.
Also, the error resolved itself without any changes from our side. We are still awaiting response from Databricks as to why the error intermittently appeared.

Comment: @niharghude Thank you for idea with regards to try block.
Good to hear the issue got resolved.